# Within-Cluster Correlation

Tags: applied-econometrics

I figured this would be more appropriate on this forum. I came across the following [slides](http://econweb.umd.edu/~sarzosa/teach/2/Disc2_Cluster_handout.pdf) after a Google search of cluster-robust uncertainty estimators. On slide 10 the author attempts to demonstrate how the errors of students nested *within* the same classroom are correlated. That is, $\textrm{E}\left[u_{ig} u_{jg'}\right] = \sigma_{(ij)g}$ if $g \neq g'$.

Shouldn't this be: if $g = g'$? I assume $g \neq g'$ represents two students ($i$ and $j$) in *different* classrooms (groups). If so, wouldn't this be demonstrative of dependence across clusters?

Sorry if this question is a bit in the weeds. Can anyone provide further clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $u_i$ is a random residue. In the linear regression model, we assume the independence of the random residue (error term). We have two slides above for case i.i.d.: $\epsilon_i \sim (0,\sigma^2)$, thus $\forall_{i\neq j}E[\epsilon_i\epsilon_j|X]=0$ and $E[\epsilon_i\epsilon_i|X]=\sigma^2$. Later (slide 10) we assume i.n.i.d. and $\forall_{g\neq g'}E[\epsilon_{ig}\epsilon_{jg'}]=0$.

Slide 12 shows the example matrix $\Omega=diag(\Sigma_g)$ that dispels doubts.

Comment: Thank you Slawomir. Assuming no ‘cross-group’ relationship, the within-group correlation should only manifest when $g = g’$. Is this a correct statement?

Comment: ... but the correlation of what? Features or random residues in linear model?

Comment: The within-group correlation of the residuals. Should it be written: if $g = g’$?

Comment: Put differently, the expectation of the residuals is $\sigma_{(ij)}g$, *if* $g = g’$?

Comment: You are right Tom, the order of the lines has been changed there. In this case, we have residuals ​​that are independent, non-identically distributed (i.n.i.d.).

Comment: So slide 10 is not the correct formulation? I appreciate the insight!

Comment: I think so. I think it's a minor editorial mistake.

Comment: Thank you. I thought something was awry at first glance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105585/discussion-between-tom-and-slawomir-jarek).